# Make my fedora-22 kde boot faster

Tags: fedora, boot, dual-boot

I am using fedora-22 kde with windows dual boot.
When I select fedora from boot menu it takes upto 20sec to boot.

I don't know if there are some programs affecting the boot time.

when I run the following command

```
$systemd-analyze
```

It shows the following result:

```
Startup finished in 4.137s (firmware) + 6.146s (loader) + 953ms (kernel) + 6.865s (initrd) + 51.146s (userspace) = 1min 9.248s
```

How can I make booting as faster as windows?

update:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
```

results

```
 10.241s dev-mapper-fedora\x2droot.device                                                                                                                       
 9.119s akmods.service                                                                                                                                         
 8.679s systemd-udev-settle.service                                                                                                                            
 8.520s mysqld.service                                                                                                                                         
 7.675s accounts-daemon.service                                                                                                                                
 7.137s firewalld.service                                                                                                                                      
 3.280s mcelog.service                                                                                                                                         
 3.191s systemd-logind.service                                                                                                                                 
 3.150s gssproxy.service                                                                                                                                       
 3.146s akmods-shutdown.service
 3.104s rtkit-daemon.service
 2.701s lvm2-monitor.service
 2.539s abrtd.service
 2.329s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
 2.220s chronyd.service
 1.941s packagekit.service
 1.791s lvm2-pvscan@8:8.service
 1.747s plymouth-start.service
 1.736s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
 1.645s rsyslog.service
 1.432s avahi-daemon.service
 1.374s wpa_supplicant.service
 1.067s fedora-readonly.service
 1.053s systemd-journal-flush.service
 . . .
```

And the command

```
$ systemd-analyze plot
```

results a XML file you can find[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hl553lm4qzsbcl/plot.xml?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the other command line options of systemd-analyze to get a better overview about what delays your boot. Your command showed that most of the time is eaten up by userspace processes. Therefore I recommend investigating this further.

Take a look at

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

and

```
systemd-analyze plot
```

The first one will give you a per process list of the delay, the second one will draw a nice graph.

This article is not specifically for Ubuntu but should also work for you and describes the procedure very well

[Arch Linux Wiki - Improve boot performance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/improve_boot_performance)

Comment: Updated the question